# Problems building using gradle with nd4j

Tags: java, gradle, nd4j

I'm trying to build a module using `nd4j`.
It builds fine with maven but not with gradle.
I did an auto-conversion of the pom, I added the `javacpp` dependency by hand and
it builds but the tests fail with link error `no jniopenblas_nolapack in java.library.path`. 
I've done a lot of net-searching to no avail. 
This is my `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
implementation("org.bytedeco:openblas:0.3.17-1.5.6")
implementation("org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.6")
implementation("org.nd4j:nd4j-native:1.0.0-M1.1")
}
```

(I've removed deps not associated with this)
A bit at my wits end, actually.

Comment: Add dependencies whose names end with "-platform" instead.

Comment: Apologies you had a frustrating experience. I ask that you know that when publishing the code we're not trying to make your life worse on purpose. I'll answer below with something that helps you understand the library as best as possible. I hope it will help you and others who find this post. I would appreciate feedback to improve the site.

Comment: @AdamGibson No need to apologise, it's Open Source and I get what I pay for :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the comments I would appreciate comments on our docs to help improve the site. We cover this scenario explicitly. I'll summarize it below then comment with a link. If you see anything missing please do help us improve the website for the future.

Nd4j uses javacpp which relies on classifiers to determine how to include native binaries. The way it works is the core classes are put in a standalone library/artifactId (nd4j-native) and it needs an accompanying classifier dependency to go with it. This will be an artifact id with the same name and version plus an additional classifier. This will usually be the OS and architecture name for your platform. This could be linux-x86_64 (linux on 64 bit intel) or android-arm64 (android on 64 bit ARM devices)

These also usually have accompanying dependencies such as openblas (which we also use the javacpp bindings for) to enable us to access fast 3rd party math routines.

With that in mind a dependency block like this is usually what you're looking for:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-native:1.0.0-M1.1"
    // Use windows-x86_64 or linux-x86_64 if you are not on macos
    compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-native:1.0.0-M1.1:macosx-x86_64"
    compile "org.bytedeco:openblas:0.3.17-1.5.6:macosx-x86_64" 
    compile "org.bytedeco:openblas:0.3.17-1.5.6" 
}
```

You can also do what Sam described earlier and use the -platform dependencies. These are going to be much easier to work with and are what we actually by default have on the docs site. This would then just be:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:1.0.0-M1.1"
 
}
```

There are further docs on this on the site so I will try to omit all of that for simplicity. If you need follow up comments please do let me know or submit another question.

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked as a charm. I got this link from the error logs on the test:  'For more information, please refer to : https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/nd4j/backend' but that link was dead. 
I was unable to find the explanation on the site but this works!

Comment: I'll look in to that thanks a lot.